Help needed with computing a complex integral
I am having trouble calculating the integral
$$
I \equiv \int_{0}^{\infty}\sin\left(r\right)r^{n - 2}\log\left(r\right)\,{\rm d}r\quad
\mbox{where}\ n\ \mbox{is an integer and}\ n > 1.
$$

I am pretty sure the logarithm has a branch cut at $0$ to $\infty$.
I have already used $2$ contours, one quarter circle and one semicircle but none of them yield results.
I always end up with an integral that I cannot solve.
In the quarter circle case, the integral on the imaginary axis yields
$$
{\rm i}^{n - 2}\int_{\infty}^{0}{\rm e}^{-t}t^{n - 2}
\log\left(t\right)\ {\rm d}t
$$
which I do not know how to approach.
On the semi circle case, I get this
$$
-i^{n-2}\int_{\infty}^0 e^{-it} \, t^{n-2} \, \log t dt
$$
which is also problematic.

Any ideas are welcome.

Hi, what if $n\geq 2$ ? Do you have convergence ?

I am not sure. both $r^{n-2}$ and $\log r$ goes to infinity for $r \to \infty$, but maybe the sine would take care of the divergence since the negative parts cancel out with the positive parts.

In order to assess that : write $[0,+\infty[=\cup_{n=0}^\infty[n\pi, (n+1)\pi]$ and cut your integral.

I think it only converges for $0<n<2$

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iverson}[1]{\left[\left[\,{#1}\,\right]\right]}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#44f}{\large\tt I} & \equiv
\color{#44f}{\left.\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin\pars{r}
\,r^{n - 2}\,\ln\pars{r}\,\dd r
\right\vert_{\,0\ <\ n\ <\ 2}}\quad:\
{\LARGE ?}
\\ - & --------------------- 
\end{align}
\begin{align}
& \mbox{Lets consider}\ \oint_{\cal C}\expo{\ic z}
z^{\nu - 2}\,\,\dd z
\\ & \mbox{where}\
\left.\rule{0pt}{5mm}{\cal C}\,\right\vert_{R\ >\ 0} =
\pars{0,0} \to \pars{R,0} \to R\exp\pars{\ic\pars{0,{\pi \over 2}}} \to \pars{0,0}.
\\ & \mbox{Clearly, the above integral -along}\ {\cal C}
\mbox{-}\ vani\!shes\ out.
\\[5mm] & \mbox{Therefore,}\ 0 =
\Im\int_{0}^{R}\expo{\ic r}r^{\nu - 2}\,\,\dd r
\\ & + \Im\,\,\,\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
\bracks{\expo{\ic R\cos\pars{\theta}}
\,\expo{-R\sin\pars{\theta}}}
\bracks{R^{\nu - 2}\,\expo{\ic\pars{\nu - 2}\theta}}
R\expo{\ic\theta}\ic\,\dd\theta}_{\ds{{\cal A}\pars{R}}}
\\ & + \Im\int_{R}^{0}\expo{\ic\pars{\ic y}}\
y^{\nu - 2}\ \expo{\pars{\nu - 2}\pi\ic/2}\,\,\ic\,\dd y
\\[5mm] & \mbox{Note that}\
0 < \verts{{\cal A}\pars{R}} <
R^{\nu - 1}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
\expo{-R\sin\pars{\theta}}\,\,\dd\theta <
R^{\nu - 1}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
\expo{-2R\theta/\pi}\,\,\dd\theta
\\[5mm] = & \
R^{\nu - 1}\pars{{\pi \over 2}{1 - \expo{-R} \over R}}
\sr{{\rm as}\ R\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\ {\pi \over 2}{1 \over R^{2\ -\ \nu}} \sr{{\rm as}\ R\ \to\ \infty}{\to}
{\LARGE 0}\,\,\, \mbox{because}\,\,\, \nu < 2.
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
& \int_{0}^{\infty}\sin\pars{r}r^{\nu - 2}\,\,\dd r =
-\cos\pars{\pi\nu \over 2}\,\,\Gamma\pars{\nu - 1} 
\\[2mm] \implies &
\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin\pars{r}r^{\nu - 2}
\,\,\ln\pars{r}\,\dd r =
\Re\totald{\bracks{\expo{\nu\pi\ic/2}\,\,\Gamma\pars{\nu - 1}}}{\nu}
\\[5mm] & \mbox{With the}\ \nu \to\ n\ \mbox{limit}:
\\[5mm] &
\bbx{\color{#44f}{\begin{array}{rl}
& \ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin\pars{r}r^{\nu - 2}
\,\,\ln\pars{r}\,\dd r}
\\ \ds{=} &
\ds{\Gamma\pars{n - 1}\bracks{\Psi\pars{n - 1}\cos\pars{n\pi \over 2} -
{1 \over 2}\pi\sin\pars{n\pi \over 2}}}
\end{array}}} \\ &
\end{align}
